# Cannot setImageResource

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gridview

I'm trying to build an android app to stream online radio.
Currently it starts to shape up and works like this: When I click on a gridview item in `MainActivity`, it starts the `AndroidMediaPlayer` activity that streams a fixed url and shows a fixed image that doesn't represent the users selection.

**Code:** https://github.com/sthlmj/IORadio/tree/clickable-funktionen/app/src/main/java/se/mookito/ioradio

Now I am trying to make it work properly, so that if I click on a certain gridview item, the image and the stream url should play according to the selection. I started by trying to get the picture to be displayed correctly by trying to pass clicked `position` from the `MainActivity`
of the `items` `ArrayList` in `MyAdapter` via `intent` so that I can `setImageResource` on the second activity `AndroidMediaPlayer` according to selected image from the first activity MainActivity.

In the second activity I tried to get the intent data:

```
//Selected image id
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);

//Set image id
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mp3Image);
imageView.setImageResource(myAdapter.items.get(position));
```

But I got: 
`'setImageResource(int)' in 'android.widget.ImageView' cannot be applied to '(se.mookito.ioradio.MyAdapter.Item)'`

Comment: Have you checked that position is valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `imageView.setImageResource(myAdapter.items.get(position).drawableId);` instead.

Comment: he should set getter and setter in item class